# convert array in to single variable

Tags: php, arrays

Hi I have the following snippet of code, which takes an ip block range and fills in the numbers in between.

```
 function ip_range($start, $end) {
 $start = ip2long($start);
 $end = ip2long($end);
 return array_map('long2ip', range($start, $end) );
 }

 $range_one = "81.133.56.0";
 $range_two = "81.133.63.255";
 print_r( ip_range($range_one, $range_two) );
```

this outputs an array like this.

```
Array ( [0] => 81.133.56.0 [1] => 81.133.56.1 [2] => 81.133.56.2 [3] => 81.133.56.3 [4] => 81.133.56.4 [5] => 81.133.56.5 [6]
```

and so on.

What I want to do is lookup each ip address using an api, like this.

```
$url = 'http://www.ipaddressapi.com/l/key?h=' . urlencode ($ip);
```

What I am having trouble doing is replacing the $ip section at the end of the API link with the array, any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Look up `foreach` in the manual.

Comment: can someone explain why people are downvoting this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `foreach` loop.

```
foreach($arrayIP as $ip){
    $url = 'http://www.ipaddressapi.com/l/key?h=' . urlencode ($ip);  

    //Other code to be executed
}
```